# Cannot open JSP form page by a GET method whose model attribute name is the same as the form's one

Tags: java, spring, jsp

When I open localhost:8080/customers/searchCustomer, it raises the exception:

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'ssn' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'ssn' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

My getter and setter are ok.

My entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String ssn;
private int age;
private String emailAddress;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
public String getSsn() {
    return ssn;
}
public void setSsn(String ssn) {
    this.ssn = ssn;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress;
}
public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}

}
```

in my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

@Autowired
private CustomerService service;

// .....

@GetMapping("/searchCustomer")
public String searchCustomer(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("customerBySsnForm", new String());
    return "searchCustomer";
}

@PostMapping("/showCustomer")
public String showCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customerBySsnForm") String ssn, Model model) {
    Customer customer = service.getCustomerBySsn(ssn).get();
    model.addAttribute("customerInShowCustomer", customer);
    return "showCustomer";
}
}
```

in my service:

```
public Optional<Customer> getCustomerBySsn(String ssn){
    return repository.findBySsn(ssn);
}
```

my repository:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    public Optional<Customer> findBySsn(String ssn);
}
```

my searchCustomer.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Search for customer</h3>
        <form:form method="POST" action="showCustomer" modelAttribute="customerBySsnForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="ssn">Customer SSN</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="ssn"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1:**

my main methods (for customer insertion) in the controller are:

```
@GetMapping("/addCustomer")
public String addCustomer(Model model) {
    Customer customerToAdd = new Customer();
    model.addAttribute("customerForm", customerToAdd);
    return "addCustomer";
}

@PostMapping("/addCustomerResult")
public String addCustomerResult(@ModelAttribute("customerForm") Customer customer) {
    service.addCustomer(customer);
    return "addCustomerResult";
}
```

When I enter the customer insertion form, everything is fine.
About the code, I understood that the Customer object created in the get method, added as attribute to Model, is going to be "populated" with its fields via the data I pass in the form. So I need an "entire" Customer object.
Indeed, for the case in which I get that error, trying to use the same modality of "transporting" objects via Model, I guess I need to add an attribute to Model with just a String object that would be set after I insert a string into the searchCustomer ssn text area.
I see this got me to error.

Comment: I highly doubt that a `java.lang.String` has a property `ssn`. You are using the model attribute in wrong way.

Comment: ok, I have to consider objects having properties elaborated in the forms. How to go further? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I posted my issue, I was unaware that Model class stores only objects designed to render the view. I finally solved my problem.

```
@GetMapping("/searchCustomer")
public String searchCustomer(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("customerBySsnForm", new Customer());
    return "searchCustomer";
}

@PostMapping("/showCustomer")
public String showCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customerBySsnForm") Customer customer, Model model) {
    String ssn = customer.getSsn();
    customer = service.getCustomerBySsn(ssn).get();
    model.addAttribute("customerInShowCustomer", customer);
    return "showCustomer";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

change model.addAttribute("customerBySsnForm", new String()); to model.addAttribute("customerBySsnForm", new Customer());

change @ModelAttribute("customerBySsnForm") String ssn to @ModelAttribute("customerBySsnForm") Customer customer
use customer.getSsn() to get value

Comment: I am going to do that. But I would like to ask.. an "entire" Customer object is needed in the Customer insertion because it would get set up with the data I pass in the form for insertion. Why to do as you say whereas in the form that should retrieve a customer by its ssn I pass just a String, to be set with the datum inserted, with which only I cannot instantiate a Customer? :)

Comment: your solution is partial. My form now opens but I cannot retrieve the data I already have in my db. That is, I try to insert a string intended to be a ssn and I cannot retrieve the corresponding Customer.

Comment: at this point, how to define the corresponding POST method fired from submitting the ssn string?

Comment: Hello. Yesterday finally I solved :) your answer is right :)